# Can a Tkinter dialog be tied to a parent who is a completely different application

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to both python and gui programming.

I am working on a python script which would pop-up a Tkinter dialog which needs to sit on top of another application (say Outlook for example) and should not allow me to do anything in Outlook until I click the cancel button on the tkinter dialog or until the dialog is withdrawn.

I am looking for some examples on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but you have to be very, very careful. If you make a programming mistake you can effectively disable your computer.

What you want to do is called a "global grab". That is, you grab *all* events. You do this with the tkinter command [grab_set_global](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.Misc-class.html#grab_set_global). You should test your application by adding a timer that automatically kills your program after a set amount of time so you aren't forced to reboot.

Comment: Thanks, so I guess its not possible to do it for a particular application with a particular title? In fact to be a little more specific, I am spawning this python script in a command shell from Eclipse and I don't want the user to be able to do anything until an OK button is pressed in this python dialog.